# Building static library and adding it to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linker, static-libraries

So I've been trying to add the Semantics3 objective-c code to a project I'm working on. I followed the directions they had on their Github page to no avail, I always get an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` linking error, even though prior to creating the builds i made sure `valid architectures` in build settings contained `armv7 armv7s arm64` and that the right targets were selected. I also made sure I was adding the `.a` file that was in the universal folder in `/Product`. Not exactly knowing if I built their code right, however, I tried going through "adding a static library to your code" section in http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial, I do everything correctly, the compiler finds the header files, but then after I add the static library, the project still won't build and I still get the same error. I read through numerous answers on SO and elsewhere online, and nothing I did seemed to fix the issue. What could be wrong?

Comment: For the iOS Simulator you should also add x86_64 & i386 to your valid architectures